# ivar is inside two blocks

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, objective-c-blocks

I have an ivar like this declared on interface:

```
BOOL controllerOK;
```

I have to use this ivar inside a block that resides itself in a block. Something like

```
myBlockl = ^(){
  [self presentViewController:controller
    animated:YES
    completion:^(){
      if (controllerOK)
        [self doStuff];
      }];
};
```

If I try to do that, I see a warning:

> **capturing self strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle**

for the if (controllerOK) line.

This does not appear to be one of those blocks problems that you create another variable using __unsafe_unretained before the block starts. First because this instruction cannot be used with a BOOL and second because the ivar controllerOK has to be tested on runtime inside the block. Another problem is that the block itself is declared on the interface, so it will be used outside the context where it is being created.

How do I solve that?

Comment: The code quoted above is not real code. Voted to close.

Comment: @matt: why is it "not real code"?

Comment: @newacct See my answer below: if you just copy and paste that code into an app (and implement the needed declarations etc.) there is no such error. So the question must not be showing what the code really is.

Comment: @matt: if `myBlockl` is an instance variable, then it does (and it's a warning, not an error)

Comment: @newacct Ah. So that's what he meant by "the block itself is declared on the interface". You've solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
__weak id this = self;
myBlockl = ^(){
  [self presentViewController:controller
    animated:YES
    completion:^(){
      if (this->controllerOK)
        [this doStuff];
      }];
};
```

Comment: But doesn't that initial reference to `self` generate a strong reference also? Also, when I try to compile this, I get an error "Member reference base type 'id' is not a structure or union".

Comment: `id` should be replaced with the actual class name (and a pointer). I don't think the initial `self` is a problem. The cycle comes from the `self` references in the inner most block because those would be retained by a method being called by `self`.

Comment: how does this help? instead of capturing and retaining `self`, you are now capturing and retaining `this`, which points to the same object

Comment: @newacct I forgot the __weak. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`controllerOK` implicitly compiles as `self->controllerOK` because it needs to access its memory location *through* `self`. Because of that, it **is** *"one of those blocks problems"*, although in this case just a simple `BOOL` variable will do.

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
myBlockl = ^(){
    BOOL isControllerOK = controllerOK;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^(){
        if (isControllerOK)
        {
            [weakSelf doStuff];
        }
    }];
};
```

I put `_weak` there because even if you fix the warning message for `controllerOK`, you'll get it again in `[self doStuff]`

Comment: That is irrelevant since I am explaining the relationship between the iVar and `self`. Unlike the other answers here that just work through how to get it *work* I tried to explain why the warning exists.

Comment: I am also talking about the relationship. You said "controllerOK implicitly compiles as self.controllerOK". That is factually incorrect. `self.controllerOK` is identical in the language to `[self controllerOK]`; whereas `controllerOK` is identical to `self->controllerOK`.

Comment: Okay. Another thing is that now you are now remembering the value of the `isControllerOK` at the time the block is created, rather than using the value at the time the block is run. Not sure whether there is a difference in this case, but in general, they are different.

Comment: You are right. `isControllerOK` could be declared inside `myBlock` just above `presentViewController`, but still technically too early. Personally, this is too much trouble just to keep `controllerOK` an iVar instead of a property. But that's another topic for another question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace references to your objects with `weak` references.

The typical fix is to declare a local variable:

```
__weak id weakSelf = self;
```

As rmaddy's observed, referring to an ivar, `controllerOK`, also generates a strong reference cycle. You can replace `BOOL controllerOK` ivar with an object:

```
NSNumber *controllerOK;
```

and then you can use a `weak` reference to that, such as in the following:

```
controllerOK = @YES;

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
__weak NSNumber *weakControllerOk = controllerOK;

myBlockl = ^(){
    [weakSelf presentViewController:controller
                           animated:YES
                         completion:^(){
                             if ([weakControllerOk boolValue])
                                 [weakSelf doStuff];
                         }];
};
```

Comment: no, the problem is controllerOK. I did what you said and the problem persists. Xcode is complaining about controllerOK.

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper Did you replace both occurrences of `self`? The reason I ask is your error message explicitly references `self`...

Comment: You can't reference any ivars either. `controllerOK` is really `self->controllerOK`. See my answer.

Comment: I resolved this issue by replacing `BOOL controllerOK` with `NSNumber *controllerOK`, which you can set as `controllerOK = @YES`, and then you can use a weak reference to that.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to do this NSNumber stuff. It used to be `controllerOk`, which is `self->controllerOk`, which captures `self`. You just need to change it to `weakSelf->controllerOk`

Comment: @newacct Doesn't weakSelf->controllerOK generate a fault if weakSelf is nil? You can check for that in your code, but don't you still get the following compiler warning? "Dereferencing a __weak pointer is not allowed due to possible null value caused by race condition, assign it to strong variable first"

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you are not in fact quoting your actual code. I tried your code and it compiled under ARC with no warning. But I had to modify it a little because your syntax for declaring a block is wrong. Thus you clearly did not copy and paste your actual code. It is a waste of time for people to try to help you if you don't show the real code that is giving trouble.

Answer (score -1):

can you try like this

```
myBlockl = ^(){

    [self presentViewController:controller
                       animated:YES
                     completion:^(BOOL isFinished){
                                if (isFinished == controllerOK)
                                      [self doStuff];
                                  }];
};
```

I am not very familiar about blocks but it worked for me.....

Answer (score -1):

unfortunately the only solution that worked was to convert BOOL controllerOK to a property nonatomic, assign and then use it inside the block.

I have tested all solutions you have posted here, without success.

Comment: Agreed. When I replaced the `controllerOK` with a nonatomic, it seems to work fine.